# Where will the content begin in a post request?

Tags: http, post, network-programming, http-proxy

I'm creating a proxy server for class, and I'm currently parsing the client request. When I get a POST request, how do I know where the headers end and the content begins? Is there a header that always comes last?

Comment: Have you though about looking inside RFCs? http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be after the blank line (CRLF = carriage return, line feed, i.e. blank lines). There should be two of these after the last header, one to go to next line and another to create a blank line. Then the content will begin.

```
POST /enlighten/rest HTTP/1.1
Host: api.opencalais.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

licenseID=string&content=string&/paramsXML=string
```

got from: http://www.opencalais.com/HTTPexamples